# How to navigate heading in focus mode- using NVDA/JAWS screenreader

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

When screen reader is in focus mode, how can we navigate to headings using keyboard shortcut? (pressing H in focus mode make an input as H in the form field). I tried using Inser+H but does not seems to work, Is using Insert+H is the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change NVDA to browse mode to using NVDA keyboard shortcut (keyboard shortcut is not available in focus mode)